# Ruby on Rails - passing DateTime as parameter in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, url, parameters, zone

My URL has `start` parameter as `2015-06-11T11:34+01:00`

URL: `/admin?start=2015-06-11T11:34+01:00`

```
start_date = params[:start]
```

When I try to display `start_date`, I receive `2015-06-11T11:34 01:00` which has `+` missing. `start_date.to_time` displays `2015-06-11 11:34:00 UTC`. This means it doesn't matter what I send after `+` i.e., `+01:00 or +05:00`.

In my ruby console I correctly receive `start_date` as `2015-06-11 10:24:00 UTC`

Please let me know how to retrieve the value of start parameter without the `+01:00` getting ignored.

Comment: `params[:start].to_s`

Answer (score 0):

Get the `param` value as a string:

```
start_date = params[:start].to_s
```